# what kind of parameters can I pass to XMLHttpRequest.send()?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a request that looks like this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
[...]
xhr.send("param1=" + obj.param1 + "&param2=" + val);
```

I'd really prefer to write something like

```
xhr.send( {"param1": obj.param1, "param2": val} );
```

(A) Is it possible to do that?

(B) Where can I find a spec that would answer that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that?

Not currently, but such things are included in the draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method. XmlHttpRequest should be able to send ArrayBuffers, Blobs, Documents, strings and FormData objects ([examples at html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-formdata)).

However, sending objects is not supported - they'd need to be serializable. You could send them as a JSON string, or use one of the many library function to generate URL argument strings (like [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)).

> Where can I find a spec that would answer that question?

I've linked the spec above, though for browser support you'd need to look at [compatibility tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest#Browser_compatibility) or the browsers' documentations (eg. for FF at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29)).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this kind of thing easily with jQuery:  `jQuery.ajax({ url: http://yoururl.com, data: {"param1": obj.param1, "param2": val}});`